# Multiple specials characters replacement optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, special-characters

I need to replace all the specials characters in a string with **javascript** or jQuery.
I am sure there is a better way to do this.
But I currently have no clue.
Anyone got an idea?

```
function Unaccent(str) {
    var norm = new Array('À','Á','Â','Ã','Ä','Å','Æ','Ç','È','É','Ê','Ë','Ì','Í','Î','Ï', 'Ð','Ñ','Ò','Ó','Ô','Õ','Ö','Ø','Ù','Ú','Û','Ü','Ý','Þ','ß', 'à','á','â','ã','ä','å','æ','ç','è','é','ê','ë','ì','í','î','ï','ð','ñ', 'ò','ó','ô','õ','ö','ø','ù','ú','û','ü','ý','ý','þ','ÿ');
    var spec = new Array('A','A','A','A','A','A','A','C','E','E','E','E','I','I','I','I', 'D','N','O','O','O','0','O','O','U','U','U','U','Y','b','s', 'a','a','a','a','a','a','a','c','e','e','e','e','i','i','i','i','d','n', 'o','o','o','o','o','o','u','u','u','u','y','y','b','y');
    for (var i = 0; i < spec.length; i++) {
        str = replaceAll(str, norm[i], spec[i]);
    }
    return str;
}

function replaceAll(str, search, repl) {
    while (str.indexOf(search) != -1) {
        str = str.replace(search, repl);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: What you're looking for is called "accent folding". Use something which has been tested instead of brewing your own :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an object as a map is a good idea, but given the number of characters you're replacing, it's probably a good idea to pre-initialize the object so that it doesn't have to be re-initialized each time the function gets run (assuming you're running the function more than once):

```
var Unaccent = (function () {
    var charMap = {'À':'A','Á':'A','Â':'A','Ã':'A','Ä':'A' /** etc. **/};
    return function (str) {
        var i, modified = "", cur;
        for(i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            cur = str.charAt(i);
            modified += (charMap[cur] || cur);
        }
        return modified;
    };
}());
```

This will front-load the heavy lifting of the function to page load time (you can do some modifications to delay it until the first call to the function if you like). But it will take some of the processing time out of the actual function call.

It's possible some browsers will actually optimize this part anyway, so you might not see a benefit. But on older browsers (where performance is of greater concern), you'll probably see some benefit to pre-processing your character map.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a version using a lookup map that works a little more efficiently than nested loops:

```
function Unaccent(str) {
    var map = Unaccent.map;       // shortcut
    var result = "", srcChar, replaceChar;
    for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
        srcChar = str.charAt(i);
        // use hasOwnProperty so we never conflict with any 
        // methods/properties added to the Object prototype
        if (map.hasOwnProperty(srcChar)) {
            replaceChar = map[srcChar]
        } else {
            replaceChar = srcChar;
        }
        result += replaceChar;
    }
    return(result);
}

// assign this here so it is only created once
Unaccent.map = {'À':'A','Á':'A','Â':'A'};   // you fill in the rest of the map
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/rRpcy/

FYI, a Google search for "accent folding" returns many other implementations (many similar, but also some using regex).

---

Here's a bit higher performance version (2.5x faster) that can do a direct indexed lookup of the accented characters rather than having to do an object lookup:

```
function Unaccent(str) {
    var result = "", code, lookup, replaceChar;
    for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
        replaceChar = str.charAt(i);
        code = str.charCodeAt(i);
        // see if code is in our map
        if (code >= 192 && code <= 255) {
            lookup = Unaccent.map.charAt(code - 192);
            if (lookup !== ' ') {
                replaceChar = lookup;
            }
        }
        result += replaceChar;
    }
    return(result);
}

// covers chars from 192-255
// blank means no mapping for that char
Unaccent.map = "AAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOO OUUUUY  aaaaaaaceeeeiiiionooooo  uuuuy y";
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Jxr9u/

In [this jsperf](http://jsperf.com/accent-replacement), the string lookup version (the 2nd example) is about 2.5x faster.

Comment: Added new version that performs 2.5x faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can prepare key value pair type of array and via jquery each traverse that array.

Example :

```
function Unaccent(str) {
   var replaceString = {'À':'A','Á':'A','Â':'A'}; // add more 

   $.each(replaceString, function(k, v) {
      var regX = new RegExp(k, 'g');    
      str = str.replace(regX,v);
   });
}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rRpcy/3/)

Good Luck !!